# Instead of Date picker is there any Third Party API Calender's for iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, calendar, ekeventkit, ekevent

Which is the best Third Api calender ?? If you have any tutorial's or the code you built can share here??

That would be a great help.Especially when a third Party api is integrated with EKeventKit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- [Tapku](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tapku-calendar) calendar is one of the best calendar available on iOS.

[image: Tapku]

- Another one is [CKCalendar](https://github.com/jaykz52/CKCalendar)

For more controls please check [Cocoa Controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/)